# Shell Script to finding files in specific folder and based on "age" of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

hello i got homework to make a shell script in linux to find a file in specific folder based on the "age" of those files. and after that i want to move that file to other specific folder.

thank you before

Comment: To know about Unix. This is answer [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102691/get-age-of-given-file)

Comment: Two useful commands are likely to be `find` with `-mtime` parameter and `stat`...

Comment: Like others mentioned, a file's "age" is quite vague.  In general, UNIX filesystems keep track of 3 dates/times: last accessed, modified, and changed (HFS, used by OSX, also tracks the file creation).  And yes, you'll probably want to use the `find` command, using the flags: `-mtime`, `-maxdepth` (if just for a specific directory), and `-exec` (for the `mv` cmd and it's flags if needed).  Here's a very similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173958/find-files-newer-than-a-day-and-copy) to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the `find` command, and specify the "age" with `-mtime` (or `-newer` if age relative to other files). See `man find` for more details.

To move the files you can use `mv` (again, see `man mv`).

Directories can be passed as arguments or stored in variables and then used 
as variables in the commands.

Without knowing anything else about your assignment I'd say use something like this:

```
find <directory> -mtime <n> | xargs mv -t <destination>
```

where `xargs` is used to pass the results from `find` to the `mv` command.

Comment: To keep it all about find (and in one process), you could use the `-exec` option of `find` instead of piping the output and using xargs

Comment: when i execute this find /home/user/Documents/ -mtime -1 | xargs mv -t /home/user/Downloads/

not just the files, but folder Documents also moved to Downloads.

how to fix it?

Comment: nevermind, i got it. i just need to add -type f when i execute find

thanks for your answer bro